# Как добавлять компонент при клике на кнопку во VueJs?

Tags: javascript, html, html5, vue.js

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="form">
        <div>Email</div>
        <input type="text" class="inp" v-model="email">
        <div>Phone number</div>
        <input type="text" class="inp" v-model="phone">
        <div>FN</div>
        <input type="text" class="inp" v-model="fn">
        <div>LN</div>
        <input type="text" class="inp" v-model="ln">
        <br><br>
        <button class="send" v-bind:disabled="!formValid">Send Data</button>
        <br><br>
        <button class="Add" @click="addGuest">+</button>
        <br><br>
        <div></div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

    <script>
        let { createApp } = Vue
        let form = createApp({
            data(){
                return{
                    email: null,
                    phone: null,
                    fn: null,
                    ln: null,
                }
            },
            computed:{
                formValid(){
                    return this.email && this.phone && this.fn && this.ln
                }
            },
            methods:{
                addGuest(){
                    
                },
            },

        })

        form.component('add-guest', {
            template:`<div class="guest">
                        <div>Name</div>
                        <input type="text">
                    </div>`
        })

        form.mount('.form')
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Хочу сделать так, чтобы при клике на кнопку с классом "Add", в div под неё добавлялся компонент add-guest.

Простите если глупый вопрос, но нагуглить не смог.

Comment: Посмотрите этот [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1508329/vue-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%83/1508344#1508344) Ваш вопрос — одна из вариаций такой задачи.

Comment: @DaniilLoban Спасибо большое <3